# Does a QWidget remove itself from the GUI on destruction?

Tags: qt

If I delete a `QWidget` using `delete`, does it unregister itself from the GUI or do I have to do this manually? Is there a logical reason for this behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by "unregister"?

Comment: When I want to add a widget to a window, I have to do a `addWidget` call. Similarly I can do a `removeWidget` to remove the widget from a window. I'd like to know if a widget does this automatically wherever it has been registered when it is being `delete`'d.

Comment: Qt uses ownership system, you shouldn't be deleting widgets manually if they're owned by something else (parent will delete them).

Comment: I'm not deleting them in a destructor. What I want to know is this: when I do `delete myQWidget`, does the widget remove itself from the layout or do I have to do this explicitly before deleting it?

Comment: Good question; while the *normal* behaviour is to let parents delete their children, it is often useful to remove children directly. I've had to do this when dynamically updating a layout, for example. It always "just worked," and I assumed Qt was doing the right thing with ownership. I'm glad for the confirmation (as indicated in the Qt documentation linked to in an answer below.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you call `addWidget` on a layout or stacked widget the ownership of the widget is transferred to the layout/stacked widget. All this means is that if the layout/stacked widget gets deleted then all the widgets that were added to it get deleted too.

It's perfectly okay to delete a widget once you are finished with it *regardless of who owns it*. The ownership is simply a convenient way of clearing up the memory of a hierarchy of objects. It in no way says that the object that owns it must delete it. If that were the case then once you added all your widgets you would only be able to get rid of them all or none at all!

If you didn't want your widget to be deleted when the layout/stacked widget gets deleted then you would call `removeWidget`. Note that it's not clear where the ownership of the widget really goes. A simple test app. I just wrote suggests that `removeWidget` did not even transfer ownership away from a `QStackedWidget` at all!

So, to answer your question, Qt will correctly remove the widget from the layout/stacked widget if you delete it. Furthermore this is the *correct* way to remove the widget if it no longer belongs in the layout/stacked widget.

Comment: "Qt will correctly remove the widget from the layout/stacked widget if you delete it." Does that last "it" refer to the widget or the layout?

Comment: The widget, as that was your question.

Comment: Just checking. :) Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 7):

As already pointed out by @CatPlusPlus , Qt uses an ownership system. So whenver you add widgets to layouts or layouts to widgets and so forth the ownership of the addee is given to the adder/parent. This is usually documented in the method documentation. For example if you look at documentation for QWidget::addLayout(QLayout*), it says the Qwidget takes ownership of the QLayout. When you delete the parent it deletes all its children as well.
Read this article for more info .

[Object Trees and Ownership in Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html)

This method is very useful, because in traditional C++ the developer has to keep track of every bit of memory allocated on the heap. This ownership system however requires that the developer onl keep track of the parents.

Comment: +1 While this doesn't answer the question directly (since the question was phrased as a yes/no question, but no answer was given), the link in this answer does contain the answer "When any QObject in the tree is deleted, if the object has a parent, the destructor automatically removes the object from its parent." So +1 for this answer.